# What does on() in JavaScript do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, event-handling

I am performing some crude operations in PHP without refreshing the page.

I don't understand this `on()` function, what does it do? And what is the parameter `#add` doing here?

```javascript
$(document).on('click','#add',function(){
    var name = $('#name').text();   //name & lname-table attribut names 
    var lname= $('#lname').text();
    if(name =='')
    {
        alert("Enter name");
        return false;
    }    
    if (lname=='')
    {
        alert("Enter last name");
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: That's JavaScript, specifically the jQuery library.

Comment: This isn't PHP; this is javascript; and `on` is used to set an event

Comment: `#add` is an `id` reference to a particular element in your HTML. `on()` is a way of attaching a behaviour to an event, in this case `click`.

Comment: basically its a event attacher

Comment: check this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The **on()** method attaches one or more event handlers for the
>   selected elements and child elements.

Read more about [jQuery on() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp)

As per your code `$(document).on('click','#add')`, I guess it's creating a **delegated** event.

It will directly fired on **`#add`** id element

Answer (score 0):

That's jQuery related. Check de ['on' documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jquery.

In your php page you must have an element with the ID 'add'. This jQuery code is executed when the users performs a mouse click on the 'add' element.